# why ie thrown error while using local storage

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, local-storage, web-storage

Hey i can't figure out why my code is not working. I've pulled out my hair please take a look and tell me what's wrong with this code

Note : it's working fine in chrome and mozilla only not working in IE10 and all below versions of IE

please note that am trying by two different ways so please don't confuse in that
here is fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/rEmn6/

here is my html code

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="editable" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="SaveValue(this)"></div>
    <button onclick="clearData()" id="reset">Reset</button>
    <br>

    <textarea id="message" onKeyUp="setVal(this)"></textarea>
</div>
```

here is javascript code

```
var editable = document.getElementById('editable');

var store = window["localStorage"], storage = window.localStorage;


if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.") != 1){
    console.log(navigator);
    var msg = document.getElementById('message');
    function setVal(ths) {
        console.log(ths.value);
        storage.setItem('sms', ths.value);
    };
    if(storage.getItem('sms')){
        msg.value = storage.getItem('sms');
    }
}

function SaveValue(ths){
    var val = ths.innerHTML;
    if (val != ''){
        store.setItem('contenteditable', val)
        console.log(val);
    }
}
function clearData(){
    console.log('clear hoga');
    store.clear();
}

if (store.getItem('contenteditable')) {
  editable.innerHTML = store.getItem('contenteditable');
}
```

Comment: Instead of pulling out your hair you could have posted the thrown error.

Comment: Are you run your page via webserver or via `file://` (from local filesystem) ?

Comment: @wumm SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getItem' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @Zub am running it from my local system

Comment: @TheMechanic i believe IE doesn't work properly with localStorage when running from filesystem. I've created the page with your code and run it via webserver, and it works fine

Comment: Regardless of IE stupidity, your code is a bloody mess. The miracle is that other browsers don't choke on it. For one thing, you could tell us what it is you are trying to achieve, because your code is certainly not self-explanatory.

Comment: @Zub Actually you are winner you are awesome dude. But I wish to know that. how you know that it's not works on local machine? Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: @kuroineko what you didn't understand? and what's wrong with my code?

Comment: When I run your code in IE I got the error you've described. If I got your idea, you want the text in textarea and contenteditable div to remain even after page reload. So in IE only textarea kept the text, but it's just a feature of IE - it saves your text by default. If you want to ensure that it works on webserver, here is my test page: http://deskimage.hostzi.com/stack-overflow-test.html

Comment: I would recommend to use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) (or similar tool) for development purpose. When you run your page from local filesystem, you can't guarantee that everything works like on webserver. That's why I **never** run my pages from local system

Comment: @Zub you are right actually i made a mistake i forgot to check it online and put it in `wamp` am always use wamp but this time am just trying for test `localStrage` and all this things happen by the way thanks a lot for helping me thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying `localStorage` on a local machine and without use of a web server like `WAMP`, `XAMPP` or similar programs. IE browser will definitely throws an error. So make sure that you are trying it in a web server for development purposes.

**When you run your page from local filesystem, the browser will not act like he does for web server.**

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is what you wanted to achieve :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <button onclick="localStorage.clear()">Reset</button>
    <br>
    <textarea id="message"></textarea>
</div>
<script>
function init()
{
    function setup (name, prop)
    {
        function save (prop)
        {
            localStorage.setItem (this.id, this[prop]);
        }

        var elem = document.getElementById(name);

        // retrieve value
        elem[prop] = localStorage.getItem (name) || '';

        // setup save handler
        //elem.onkeyup = save.bind (elem, prop);
        elem.onkeyup = function (e,p) {          // IE8+ compat.
                           return function () {
                               save.call (e, p); 
                           };
                       }(elem, prop);
    }

    setup ('editable', 'innerHTML');
    setup ('message' , 'value');
}

window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Your code was flawed in so many ways I reckoned it was easier to rewrite it from scratch:

- complete duplication of code for the saving/restoring of your 2 elements, with the code located in two different places while the problem is basically the same
- confusing names ('ths' is an eyesore. The first time I checked your code I automatically identified it as a typo for 'this')
- wrong way of defining event handlers and passing them parameters (defining event handlers inside HTML code is causing all sorts of problems, since you can't access anything but `this` and global variables)
- mumble-jumble of global and local variables (due to the definition of the event handlers inside HTML)
- your code did not work in the fiddle since all your global functions were moved into the init procedure

It was much less work (at least for me) to rewrite it than to try to rebuild a functional version and then try to understand what went wrong with it.

I dumped the attempt at detecting whatever IE7 version. It was getting in the way, since your problem was targeting IE10 anyway. As a side note, a site using this kind of features should simply drop IE7- compatibility altogether, IMHO.

I tested this code on IE8/XP, FF, Opera, Chrome, IE11 and safari/XP.

All tests were run from a web server except IE11. It is well possible IE10- have problems with local storage when run localy.

Comment: your code is good i really appreciated this thanks a lot.
but i would like to tell you one thing that i wrote by two ways for check which one is perfect. that's why i wrote this kind btw thanks a lot for give me a inspiration :-)

Comment: one more thing the problem is that am not using wamp or something like that i tried it on local machine. that's why code is threw error

Comment: Ah well, it worked locally on IE11 for me, but maybe the local storage is broken on IE10?

Comment: +1 for make function simple and easier hat's off dude

Comment: My pleasure :). Note that you can use `elem.onkeyup = save.bind (elem, prop)` if you don't need to support IE8. It should work for IE9+.

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer 11 I get the error message  `SaveValue is undefined` appearing here:

```
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="SaveValue(this)"></div>
```

You should be using unobtrusive Javascript techniques and place the onKeyUp event handling in your script instead of in the div.

```
var editable = document.getElementById('editable');
editable.onkeyup = SaveValue;
```

In your SaveValue function you can now use `this.innerHTML` to get the text

This should save you some tears