# local storage cookies fall back

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have created a local storage function to save and then load the shopping cart from the cookies but when I try to access this page on another machine, it gives me error. how do I add a fall back to these functions so that if the code is viewed on a server or another machine locally it will work on there too and store new cookies basically.

```
ShoppingBasket.saveCart = function() {
    localStorage.setItem("shoppingCartCookie", JSON.stringify(this.cart));
};


// function to load cart
ShoppingBasket.loadCart = function() {
    this.cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCartCookie"));
};
```

This is the code that causes the problem...

```
ShoppingBasket.addItemToCart = function(name, price, count) {
    for (var i in this.cart) {
        if (this.cart[i].name === name) {
            this.cart[i].count += count;
            this.saveCart();
            return;
        }
    }
    var item = new this.Item(name, price, count);
    this.cart.push(item);
    this.saveCart();
};
```

It causes the error message, `Cannot read property 'push' of null`

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Cannot read property 'push' of null

Comment: There's nothing using `push()` so you can't tell exactly what's causing it.  It's likely to be a lack of `localStorage` on the machine in question, but you need to investigate more.  Have you tried to open the console and just type `typeof localStorage`?  If you get `object` then that's not the problem.

Comment: Thansk the push is in my other functions, I have read online that it needs a fall back for when the cookie is not on that machine. but I dont know how it is. is there any better way to store the array when run on server or different machines?

Comment: A fallback is a great suggestion, but I'd recommend getting your existing code working before adding anything else.  Fix the push error first and then take it from there.

Comment: when I typed that in the console it just brings "object" and when I add to basket then it brings that Cannot read property 'push' of null  error and does not add to the basket nor stores it in cookie.

Comment: In that case, `localStorage` has nothing to do with your problem.  Fix that first and then look at this other issue (which may or may not be an issue).

Comment: thanks but my code works great in the machine I first developed it on. when I copied the file on my USB and used it on another machine it brings that error and I read online that its because of the way I stored the cookie. what is the best way to store the array that works when putting it on the server ?

Comment: What you read is not pertinent to this problem.  What do you mean by "putting it on the server"?  Are you trying to run this code as a server application?  If it's running in a browser then you need to fix the error message you are getting, not something else.

Comment: thanks, the code worked when the cookie was saved and now the cart brings null as results. so there's nothing getting pushed to the cart. I havent changed anything on the code.

Comment: Sorry but the code you've posted is fine, and the fact that `typeof localStorage` returns `object` means that there is absolutely nothing wrong with what you've posted.  The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: thanks for confirming, the code is too long to post is there anyway I get help on why Im having this issue or how to fix it? its very strange as sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt. I just dont understand why.

Comment: You need to go back to the error message and inspect the code that's causing that.  It should tell you where in the code to look (script name and line number).

Comment: yes its bascially saying that it doesnt see any items in the array to push it in. so I tried few things. I removed the ShoppingBasket.loadCart(); that I had at the end of my code and it worked but when I refreshed the page it didnt load the data that was saved. so what should I do to be able to load the saved data and not get this error message?

Comment: If the array is null then look at where it's created.  Start outputing variables to the console so you can see what's going on, or even better, step through the code with the developer tools and follow what's happening, comparing it to what should be happening.  This is just something you're going to have to debug yourself, as you can't even supply the code that's causing the error you're trying to fix.

Comment: code thats cauring error is the part  this.cart.push(item); from this code section :               ShoppingBasket.addItemToCart = function (name, price, count) {
            for (var i in this.cart){
                if (this.cart[i].name === name) {
                    this.cart[i].count += count;
                     this.saveCart();
                    return;
                }
            }
        
            var item = new this.Item(name, price, count);
          
            this.cart.push(item);
     
            this.saveCart();
        };

Comment: `this.cart` is null, and it has nothing to do with whether you use `localStorage` or cookies, since `localStorage` clearly works on the machine you're having problems on.  Start there and investigate.  Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probebly your cart is null in localstorage
check if cart is null then sett to new array

```
ShoppingBasket.loadCart = function() {
    this.cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCartCookie")) || [];
};
```

Comment: thanks so much this worked but when I run it in IE it gives me this error :Unable to get property 'setItem' of undefined or null reference

Comment: This also can issue with IE if it works in other browsers.

Comment: Found it. There is a issue on IE 10.. here is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/21372954/5409081

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check that the key is existing in local storage -

```
if ("shoppingCartCookie" in localStorage) {
//Your logic 
}else{
//Your logic to create cookie
}
```

Local storage is machine specific, so for each macjine you first need to store  the shoppingCartCookie, then only you will be able to access that.

Hope this will help you.